# The "multifunction" version of ZPP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes, terminology

I would like to ask if there is a name for the class of [multifunctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function), each of which can be computed by a probabilistic polytime Turing machine $M$ satisfying the following two conditions:

1. $M$ returns a correct output of the function with high probability
2. $M$ can either return a correct answer or "don't know", and never return an incorrect answer.

Note that although this sounds like [$\mathsf{ZPP}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPP_%28complexity%29), it is not since $\mathsf{ZPP}$ is the class of predicates, and not multifunctions. I really appreciate any pointer to the right sources.

Comment: Is the output of the multivalued function nonetheless in $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$?

Comment: No, outputs are binary strings.

Comment: As I understand it, “multifunction version” is more commonly referred to as “search version,” “relation version” or “function version” (which is a misnomer and potentially confusing) in complexity theory.  Although I do not know any particular paper which discusses the relation version of ZPP, I will be surprised if there is none because the notion seems very natural.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: I completely agree!

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito or @Dai Le: I don't see the motivation to define a "multifunction version" if I have a "decision version". Perhaps I have missed something in my complexity theory lecture :)

Comment: @Marc: Many problems which we care about in the real world are relation problems, not decision problems (we need some answer which is not just yes/no).  On the other hand, restricting our attention to decision problems often makes the arguments in complexity theory (such as reductions) simpler.  Therefore a comparison between decision problems and relation problems is important when it is nontrivial.  Without such a comparison, discussions restricted to decision problems may lose the connection to real-world problems, which is not the end of the world but not a happy thing either.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: Of course there are non decision problems in the real world but I thought the decision problems and the search problems are [turing equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) (not all but all practical problems).

Comment: @Marc: in many cases, you can easily reduce function problems to decision problems, so the function version is not really needed. In this case, I don't see how to reduce the defined multifunction problems to ZPP problems.

Comment: @Marc: That is not a provable claim.  To formulate that claim in a provable form, we need a definition.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito and @Dai Le: Let me suprise :) Perhaps this is a new question but what are the names of the "multifunction version" of $P$, $NP$, $BPP$, $RP$, ...?

Comment: @Marc: FP and FNP for the first two. Incidentally, PPAD is an example of a class of problems for which decision is trivial (always YES), but search is nontrivial

Comment: @Dai Le: I think maybe what you're looking for is Las Vegas algorithms, but I'm not sure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm. I do not know that the class of functions computable by polytime Las Vegas algorithms has an abbreviate beyond "Las Vegas polynomial time".

Comment: I always thought ZPP was the class of las vegas algorithms

Comment: @Joshua: "Las Vegas algorithms" seem right! At least, that's how Babai defined Las Vegas algorithms.  "Las Vegas polynomial time" seems like a very reasonable name. Although I don't think you need more points :-), would you like to make it an answer?

Comment: @Suresh: ZPP is the class of _decision_ problems which have randomized polynomial-time algorithms of Las Vegas type.

Comment: Tsuyoshi has it right above: these should be called ZPP search algorithms (or Las Vegas search algorithms).

Comment: @Suresh: you can model a promise problem within the search version of P, but not, as far as I know, within FP, so I don't see how these classes can be strictly said to be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Las Vegas algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm). I do not know that the class of functions computable by polytime Las Vegas algorithms has an abbreviation beyond "Las Vegas polynomial time".

As pointed out by Tsuyoshi Ito in the comments, $ZPP$ is exactly the class of *decision* problems decidable in Las Vegas polynomial time.